# Matriz MxN, llenar vector con valores de matriz.

Tags: python, array, matrices

```
import random
n = int(input("Ingrese el numero de fila: \n"))
m = int(input("Ingrese el numero de columna: \n"))
#a = n*m
matriz = []

for i in range(n):  
    for j in range(m):
        matriz[i][j] = random.randint(0, 100)
 print(matriz)
```

Tengo esta forma de crear una matris pero me sale este error:

```
matriz[i][j] = random.randint(0, 100)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer primero instalas numpy

```
pip install numpy
```

Luego:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

n = int(input("Ingrese el numero de fila: \n"))
m = int(input("Ingrese el numero de columna: \n"))

matriz = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(n, m))
print(matriz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que utilizar [append](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm) para definir la matriz y asignarle sus valores. Por ejemplo:

```
import random
n = 4
m = 3
#a = n*m
matriz = []

for i in range(n):
    matriz.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        matriz[i].append(random.randint(0, 100))

print(matriz)
```

Salida:

```
$python main.py
[[7, 78, 57], [18, 3, 58], [30, 44, 17], [45, 39, 64]]
```

De esta forma, vas agregando a la matriz la cantidad de filas con el primer `for` (`matriz.append([])`), y luego vas agregando los elementos de las columnas con el segundo `for`(`matriz[i].append(elemento)`). Es resumen, primero tenés que agregar fila por fila, y luego, por cada fila agregada, vas agregando los elementos de las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Se va a salir de rango por que la variable **matriz** es una lista vacia, si dices matriz[0][0] no esta definida a menos que sea una lista de listas.

Una forma de crear una matriz es esta:

```
import random
a=[]
filas=5
columnas=4
for i in range(filas):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(columnas):
        a[i].append(random.randrange(100))

print(a)
```

Pero existe una forma mas compacta y practica de crear una matriz:

```
a=[[i for i in range(6)]for j in range(4)]
```

cuyo resultado es este:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```